# SQL Server 2008: duplicate a row n-times, where n is a value in a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

In SQL Server 2018 I have three tables:

```
T1 (idService, dateStart, dateStop)
T2 (idService, totalCostOfService)
T3 (idService, companyName)
```

Using joins, I created a view:

```
V1 (idService, dateStart, dateStop, totalCostOfService, companyName)
```

And we are fine. I can do my selects on the view and obtain the list of services done.

What I would like to do now is to duplicate every row of the view n times, where *n=dateStart-dateStop*; every row should have a "new" *totalCostOfService = totalCostOfService/n*.

I can do that using a temporary table, declaring variables, insert in temp using some *while* etc. etc. Let's call it "the procedure"

But what I would like to understand is:

is it possibile to do that directly with a select on V1? If not, is it possible to save "the procedure" as a view so that I can have it as a easy select?

Sorry if my question looks somewhat stupid, but I'm totally new with SQL. I tried searching here and on google but I couldn't find what an answer to my questions.

Thank you!

Comment: do you know 'table valued functions' and 'cross apply'? Might want to read up on those.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This kind of request, although common, is not trivial, so don't feel bad about it. Do you have a "numbers" table in your database (a table which has one row for each number from 1 to some large value)?

Comment: @gjvdkamp: no, I'm going to search. Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis: thank you for your kind words :) No, we don't have a table like that in our db. Could you please advise me on how that could be useful in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an rCTE (which is RBAR), you could use a Tally Table:

```
WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
         CROSS JOIN N N4) --10000
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
     JOIN Tally T ON T.I <= dateStart-dateStop --Assumes dateStart and DateStop are integer values, even though their name implies otherwise
                                               --If they are dates, then use DATEDIFF(DAY, dateStart, dateEnd)
```

That tally will generate numbers up to 10000 (which over 27 years worth of days. That should be far more than enough).

Comment: Thank you, this one looks like the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the existence of a `numbers` table which has the column `val` for the individual value numbers. If you don't, you will find plenty by searching around.

Add this in the end of the `FROM` clause of your view:

```
cross apply (select datediff(day,T1.dateStart,T1.dateStop)+1 as n_days)q1 -- number of days INCLUDING start
cross apply (select dateadd(day,T1.dateStart,n.val) as day_of_charge)q2 from numbers n where n.val between 0 and n_days-1)
```

Then you will be able to have the following field on your `SELECT`:

`T2.totalCostOfService/n_days as totalCostOfService`

I'll add a numbers table solution shortly.

Comment: Thanks George, looks really nice and clean. I understand the importance of the numbers table now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select idService, dateStart, dateStop,
             totalCostOfService / (datediff(day, datestop, datestart) + 1) as dailyCostOfService,
             companyName
      from v1
      union all
      select idService,
             dateadd(day, 1, dateStart),
             dateStop,
             dailyCostOfService
             companyName
      from cte
     )
select idservice, dateStart as dateOfService,
       dailyCostOfService, companyName
from cte;
```

Note that if there are more than 100 days in any row, then you will need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.